# problems after upgrading ubuntu 16.04 LTS to 18.04 LTS

Tags: unity, upgrade, 18.04, shortcut-keys, gnome-shell

So i upgraded my Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 through update center and everything went fine.
In the log in screen i am allowed to choose the GUI i want to use - e.g. unity, ubuntu, ubuntu on wayland, openbox etc...

on 16.04 i used unity now i want to start using the ubuntu option (GNOME-shell if im not wrong), however some of the softwares i downloaded to my old desktop are not willing to work on this one. one example is tor browser that won't launch on "ubuntu" but would launch normally on unity.

Another problem i came across is that i have created some bash scripts back on my old unity desktop, and bind them as a keyboard shortcuts. now after the upgrade the bind would work on unity and ubuntu desktops, but not on ubuntu on wayland.

whats up with that?

> 1) how come the desktops doesn't work all the same?
>
> 2) is there a way to get rid of a few desktops? is it recommended? does it takes up resources and worth eliminating? (Say i want to keep only a couple)
>
> 3) how do i make the key binding work on the ones that it doesnt function properly on?
>
> 4) how do i make the same software work on all desktops (e.g. tor browser) without having the necessity to reinstall?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost this is gnome not unity, things are different bare with us.
Now:

> How come the desktops don't work the same?

- That's cause they use different libraries and hence different protocols.

> How do I get rid of a few desktops?

- What few desktops are we talking about here?

> How do I make the key binding work?

- Take a few minutes to alter your scripts, remember this is gnome and a lot is different.

> How to make the same software work on desktops, 
>   for example Tor browser?

- Tor for unity isn't the same as Tor for gnome. Please save your self some drama and just reinstall.

Comment: i see... 
About the desktops: on my login screen im allowed to choose between: openbox, ubuntu, ubuntu on wayland, unity, and recently i installed lubuntu cause the gnome based shells were a bit laggy.
say i wanna have only 2 to 3 options on my computer - ubuntu/ubuntu on wayland (which look the same to me, no idea whats the difference), unity and lubuntu - how do i do it and save up some some memory?

what are the differences between the two shells? in terms of code what kind of alters are we talking about? the kind of difference between python 2 and 3 or more like python to vb?

thanks